# Remove current directory from variable containing path

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a variable which contains the current directory including several parents. For example:

```
$ pwd
/Users/simont/repositories
$ echo $current
~/repositories
```

I can strip everything *except* the current directory from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-bash-script):

```
onlycurrent=${$(current)##*/}
```

I want to do the opposite: remove the current dir from this variable (so that it only contains `~/`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dirname` you can strip off the last directory:

```
$ current="~/repositories"
$ echo $current
~/repositories
$ dirname $current
~
```

Admittedly this does not save the `/` character to the right of `~`.

If you wish to do this simply using `bash` you could do:

```
$ echo ${current%/*}
~
```

Which strips off everything after the last `/` (including the `/` itself).

Answer (score 0):

This does not solve you problem in full generality, but you may want to look at dirname (and basename)

```
/home/or..product/oracle10 >pwd
/home/oracle/product/oracle10

/home/or..product/oracle10 >dirname `pwd`
/home/oracle/product

/home/or..product/oracle10 >basename `pwd`
oracle10
```

BTW: dirname does not really care if the returned string is really a directoy, it works on arbitrary strings.

```
/home/or..product/oracle10 >dirname "/foo/bar/baz"
/foo/bar
```