# Current Directory in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am quite new to shell scripting.

I am trying to make a directory when a user runs my script using `bash scriptName.sh`.

At present my shell script looks like,

```
mkdir -p build/iphoneos/XXXXXXXXXX.txt
```

I want to know how I can put the current directory's name in place of `XXXXXXX`, in the script.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-bash-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
mkdir -p build/iphoneos/$(basename $PWD).txt
```

or

```
mkdir -p build/iphoneos/${PWD##*/}.txt
```

The first calls the `basename` binary. The second one removes all character up to the last `/` character.

Comment: + 1 for the answer!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `pwd` and parse get the last word.

Here is a way

```
foo=`pwd | rev | cut -f1 -d'/' | rev`
```

then use `$foo` instead of XXXXX