# Display the current directory name in bash terminal window

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have several terminals open in one window, with the title showing the fullpath of the current directory.  The problem I'm having is: the paths are so long it's hard to distinguish between them.

What I would like to display is the current directory name (not the full path) in the title.

Here is my current title in my .bashrc

```
   PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$$ ${BRANCH} ${PWD/#$HOME} \007"'
```

I thought just replacing the $PWD with $CWD would work, but bash doesn't have it built in.  This solution below only works the first time.
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235278/345097
After changing directories again the title never gets updated.
 
   `` export DIR=`echo $PWD | rev | cut -f1 -d'/' | rev`
   export DIR2=`basename ${PWD}`
   PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$$ ${BRANCH} ${DIR} \007"' ``

Here's my PS1 as a reference:
   `PS1="[\033[00;31m]\h [\033[00;32m] \w [\033[00;36m] > [\033[00m]"`

---

Example:

> cd /share/project/master/app/src/com/project/dao

Currently the Title displays

**5670 master /share/project/master/app/src/com/project/dao**

Desire Title 
   **5670 master dao**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `$PWD` is guaranteed to be a directory, you might use either of the following:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$$ ${BRANCH} $(basename "$PWD") \007"'
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$$ ${BRANCH} ${PWD##*/} \007"'
```

Comment: Fixed. I didn't think through if I needed `#` or `##` here. With `#`, the prefix is matched by the first `/` it finds; with `##`, the `*` matches the longest string it can before match the `/`.

Comment: I agree, the second one works now.  They both work, Thank you.

Comment: Even when I put this in my .bashrc it doesn't seem to go off unless I source .bashrc in each new tab. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Note: To avoid tilde expansion, use `dirs` instead of `$PWD`.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovič There are no unquoted expansions of `$PWD` that could undergo tilde expansion.

Comment: @chepner Sorry for not being clear. What I meant is the following: `dirs` shows `~` for the home directory whereas `${PWD##*/}` shows `X` where `X` is the username.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovič Ah, to *insert* the `~` in place of the actual path name. Actually, `bash` does provide something to accomplish that now. The prompt escape `\w` is how the shell displays the current directory in the prompt. You can use that with parameter expansion as of `bash` 4.4: `x="\w"; echo "${x@P}"`