# Passing Directory name into Ruby run statement

Tags: ruby, bash, sinatra, zsh, zshrc

I'm using `rerun` and `sinatra` enough that I wanted a nice alias so I could execute `rerun ruby X.rb` where X was the current directory (ie: `/Users/David/Documents/Projects/sample`=>`rerun ruby sample.rb`).

The command I'm using (adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-bash-script) question) is `alias sin="rerun ruby ${PWD##*/}.rb"`. When I use that, it says `ruby: No such file or directory -- David.rb (LoadError)` as if it was passed my user folder instead of the project folder.

However, when I manually source my `.zshrc` (`alias sz="source ~/.zshrc"`, which should be run on shell creation (and all my other aliases work fine, so I have no reason to believe it wouldn't be working)) and run `sin` again, it totally works as intended.

Any ideas? I'm pretty new at bash scripting. Also, I'm using zsh if that's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule about aliases is "if you have to ask, use a function instead":

```
sin() {
  rerun ruby "${PWD##*/}.rb"
}
```

which works as expected.

The particular problem in your case is that `${PWD##*/}` is expanded when you define the alias, and not when you run it. You could also fix it by using single quotes in the definition:

```
alias sin='rerun ruby "${PWD##*/}.rb"'
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I didn't even know you could make functions in config files like that. I mostly use aliases for static things that I'm tired of typing out (like `alias zshow="defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder"`). This is great though!