# using docker-compose on a kubernetes instance with jenkins - mounting empty volumes

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I have a Jenkins instance setup using Googles [Jenkins on Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-kubernetes-engine-tutorial) solution. I have not changed any of the settings of the Kubernetes Pod.

When I trigger a new job I am successfully able to get everything up and running until the point of my tests.

My tests use docker-compose. First I make sure to install docker (1.5-1+b1) and docker-compose (1.8.0-2) on the instance (I know I can optimize this by using an image that already includes these, but I am still just in proof-of-concept).

When I run the `docker-compose up` command everything works and the services start their initialization scripts. However, **the mounts are empty**. I have verified that the files exist on the Jenkins slave, and the mount is created inside the docker service when I run docker-compose, however **they are empty**.

Some information:

In order to get around file permissions I am using `/tmp` as the Jenkins Workspace. I am using SCM to pull my files (successfully) and in the docker-compose file I specify `version: '2'` and the mount paths with absolute paths. The volume section of the service that fails looks like this:

```
volumes:
 - /tmp/automation:/opt/automation
```

I changed the command that is run in the service to `ls /opt/automation` and the result is an empty directory.

**What am I missing?** *I just want to mount a directory into my docker-compose service*. This works perfectly from Windows, Ubuntu, and Centos devices. Why won't it work using the Kubernetes instance?

Comment: This may be a copy of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31381322/1561176

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason it fails [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31381323/1561176):

> A Docker container in a Docker container uses the parent HOST's Docker daemon and hence, any volumes that are mounted in the "docker-in-docker" case is still referenced from the HOST, and not from the Container.
>
> Therefore, the actual path mounted from the Jenkins container "does not exist" in the HOST. Due to this, a new directory is created in the "docker-in-docker" container that is empty. Same thing applies when a directory is mounted to a new Docker container inside a Container.

So it seems like it will be impossible to mount something from the outer docker into the inner docker. And another solution must be found.