# How fix mounting issue while using docker-compose.yml on test containers

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, testcontainers

I am using test containers to run some tests and using https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/docker_compose/ to spin some containers used for my tests. Similar to generic containers support, it's also possible to run a bespoke set of services specified in a docker-compose.yml file.

This is intended to be useful on projects where Docker Compose is already used in dev or other environments to define services that an application may be dependent upon.

Here is my code to include docker-compose.yml

```
@ClassRule
public static DockerComposeContainer environment =
    new DockerComposeContainer(new File("src/test/resources/docker-compose.yml"));
```

Here is the content of my yml file:

```
version: '2.0'
services:

  vault:
    image: vault:0.10.2
    container_name: vault
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
    environment:
      - VAULT_ADDR=http://0.0.0.0:8200
      - VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8200
      - VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=stupid-token
    volumes:
      - /config/vault/start.sh:/start.sh
    command: sh -c "./start.sh"

  consul:
    image: consul:0.8.5
    container_name: consul
    ports:
      - "8300:8300"
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:8600"
      - "8600:8600/udp"
    environment:
      - SERVICE_IGNORE=true
    entrypoint: sh -c "BIND_HOST=$$(echo \"$DOCKER_HOST\" | awk -F ':' '{print $$2}' | sed  's/\\/\\///'); echo $$BIND_HOST;/bin/consul agent -server -bootstrap  --client=0.0.0.0 --data-dir=/tmp/consul -ui -advertise=$$BIND_HOST -domain=consul-dev"

  registrator:
    image: gliderlabs/registrator:v7
    container_name: registrator
    depends_on:
      - consul
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    entrypoint: sh -c "BIND_HOST=$$(echo \"$DOCKER_HOST\" | awk -F ':' '{print $$2}' | sed  's/\\/\\///'); echo $$BIND_HOST;/bin/registrator -ip $$BIND_HOST consul://consul:8500"

  postgres:
    image: registry.xxx.com/xxx-postgres:9.5.9
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    depends_on:
      - registrator
    volumes:
      - /config/postgres/docker-entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint.sh:ro
#      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - SERVICE_NAME=postgres
    command: -c max_connections=4000

  test-dbmigrate:
    image: registry.xxx.com/test-db:master
    container_name: test-dbmigrate
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - DEV_LOGGING=1
      - DB_INIT=1
      - DB_HOST=postgres
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_USER=test
      - DB_PASSWORD=xxx
      - PGPASSWORD=xxx

#volumes:
#  postgres-data:
```

I am getting this error `{
    "timestamp": "2019-06-11T21:08:32.320Z",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "thread": "Test worker",
    "logger": " [docker/compose:1.8.0]",
    "message": "Could not start container",
    "context": "default",
    "exception": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container did not start correctly.\n\tat org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:255)\n\tat org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:212)\n\tat org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:76)\n\tat org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:210)\n\tat org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:199)\n\tat org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerisedDockerCompose.invoke(DockerComposeContainer.java:548)\n\tat org.testcontainers.containers.DockerComposeContainer.runWithCompose(DockerComposeContainer.java:211)\n\tat org.testcontainers.containers.DockerComposeContainer.createServices(DockerComposeContainer.java:165)\n\tat org.testcontainers.containers.DockerComposeContainer.start(DockerComposeContainer.java:152)\n\tat org.testcontainers.containers.DockerComposeContainer.starting(DockerComposeContainer.java:121)\n\tat org.testcontainers.containers.FailureDetectingExternalResource$1.evaluate(FailureDetectingExternalResource.java:29)\n\tat org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:117)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n"
}
    {
    "timestamp": "2019-06-11T21:08:32.348Z",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "thread": "Test worker",
    "logger": " [docker/compose:1.8.0]",
    "message": "Log output from the failed container:\nCreating network \"k66igshwvupa_default\" with the default driver\n\nCreating consul\n\nCreating vault\n\nCreating registrator\n\nCreating postgres\n\n\n\nERROR: for postgres  Cannot start service postgres: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:359: container init caused \\\"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\\\\\\"/config/postgres/docker-entrypoint.sh\\\\\\\" to rootfs \\\\\\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/df4d5e2dae646eab8079cee1b8a562c1b7d2d374340d01fecf4894e6ba64be8e\\\\\\\" at \\\\\\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/df4d5e2dae646eab8079cee1b8a562c1b7d2d374340d01fecf4894e6ba64be8e/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh\\\\\\\" caused \\\\\\\"not a directory\\\\\\\"\\\"\"\n\n: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type\n\nEncountered errors while bringing up the project.\n",
    "context": "default"
}`

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I gave a relative path:

```
volumes:
  - ./docker-entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.withLocalCompose(true)` helped me

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.