# Bash expansion: Different results when running file or running in terminal // extglob

Tags: linux, bash

In some script I want to use the name of the folders inside the current folder. I want to get folder names, and I will only put the problematic part in an example here. If I run this from the terminal, I get:

```sh
$ for D in */; do echo ${D%%+(/)} ; done
galaxya8
iphone6s
motog6
motog7

$ echo ${0}
/bin/bash

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

However, if I put that into a file and run the file I get names with trailing slashes:

```sh
$ echo 'for D in */; do echo ${D%%+(/)} ; done' >> test.sh

$ bash test.sh
galaxya8/
iphone6s/
motog6/
motog7/
```

I saw that bash expansion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1371283). What am I missing? Maybe some default value for interactive shells only?

---

[Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (Thanks @kamil-cuk):

```sh
$ D=a/; echo ${D%%+(/)}; bash <<<'D=a/; echo ${D%%+(/)}'
a
a/
```

Comment: MCVE can be shortened to just `D=a/; echo ${D%%+(/)}; bash <<<'D=a/; echo ${D%%+(/)}'`

Comment: Both ways (terminal and file) work correctly if I use `${D%/*}` instead.

Comment: To ease futur search, you should update the title to have 'extglob'.

Comment: The answer deserves the upvotes it has recieved, but so does this Q! (IMHO). Good luck to all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

> If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are recognized.
> ...
>
> +(pattern-list)
> Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.

You need enable `extglob` `shopt` option in your script to use extended pattern matching operator the `+(/)`.

```
echo 'shopt -s extglob; for D in */; do echo ${D%%+(/)} ; done' > test.sh
```