# Prompt Expansion ZSH Remove Hostname if entire PROMPT is too long

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, zshrc, ps1

Currently, my `zshrc` looks like this

```sh
setopt prompt_subst # real time reevaluation of prompt
zmodload zsh/mathfunc # int function
function widthHelper() { echo $(( int(${COLUMNS:-80}) * ${1}/100)) } # calc $1% of prompt
outWidth='$(widthHelper 40)'
inWidth='$(widthHelper 90)'
export PROMPT="%F{cyan}%${outWidth}<◀︎<%f" # truncation based on terminal width
PROMPT+="%(l." # inner truncation group
PROMPT+="%F{cyan}%8>‣>%n%>>%f" # username truncated
PROMPT+="%-${inWidth}(l. %F{blue}%5>‣>%m%>>%f.) " # hostname truncated
PROMPT+=".)" # end truncation
PROMPT+="%F{magenta}%1~%f%<< " # pwd 1 depth
PROMPT+="%# " # privilege group
```

[influenced by this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369847/how-to-configure-zsh-prompt-so-that-its-length-is-proportional-to-terminal-width)
and
[my other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680351/prompt-expansion-zsh-nested-truncation)

## what is currently working as expected

1. it truncates the hostname and the username to constant values
2. it dynamically truncates the entire PROMPT based on `widthHelper()` which allows me to resize my terminal and dynamically truncate the PROMPT

Currently, I have this line working but not in the desired way

```sh
PROMPT+="%-${inWidth}(l. %F{blue}%5>‣>%m%>>%f.) " # hostname truncated
```

## what I want

I want to have the displaying of the hostname depend on **the length of the entire `PROMPT`** and **not** just rely on the **width of the current terminal `COLUMNS`**.

i.e. I want the hostname to dissapear if I enter a directory with a very long name **before** I begin to truncate the entire prompt.  But I do want both to happen **in this order**

1. the hostname would dissapear (**this happens but is not dependent on the `PROMPT` length but on the width of the entire terminal, `COLUMNS`**)
2. the entire prompt would begin to truncate on the left (**this currently works**)

## example

If I am in a directory `~` then move into a directory with a long name `~/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd` I want the hostname to dissapear, but what is happening is that my prompt is being truncated first.

```sh
william‣ wmbp‣ ~ %                                                                          
william‣ wmbp‣ ~ % cd abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd                                        
◀︎m‣ wmbp‣ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd %
```

what I want

```sh
william‣ wmbp‣ ~ %                                                                          
william‣ wmbp‣ ~ % cd abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd                                        
william‣ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd %
```

If I could make the `# hostname truncated` line depend on the `PROMPT` length then I could solve this issue.

## tldr

How can I remove part of my `PROMPT` based on how long my current `PROMPT` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved my own problem but first I have to say the question was flawed because I am holding the length of the prompt to a solid percentage of the terminal window.  So, I can not expect the prompt to do this

```sh
william‣ wmbp‣ ~ %                                                                          
william‣ wmbp‣ ~ % cd abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd                                        
william‣ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd %
```

but what I can do is expect the terminal to do this

```sh
william‣ wmbp‣ Desktop %
william‣ wmbp‣ Desktop % cd abcdefghijk
william‣ abcdefghijk %
```

because the `%` is aligned from one line to the next.

The way I got to this solution was to use this in my `zshrc`

```sh
LENGTH_OF_USERNAME=8
LENGTH_OF_HOSTNAME=5
# calc $1% of prompt
function termWidthPercentHelper() { echo $(( int(${COLUMNS:-80}) * ${1}/100)) }
function hostNameInPromptHelper() {
    # if you are in the home directory or if you are in a directory with a name
    # that has a length which is less than $1% of the terminal's width
    if [[ ${PWD##*/} == ${HOME##*/} ]] || [[ ${#PWD##*/} -lt $(termWidthPercentHelper $1) ]] then
        echo "%F{blue}%${LENGTH_OF_HOSTNAME}>‣>%m%>>%f "
    fi
}
PROMPT_PERCENTAGE='$(termWidthPercentHelper 30)'
HOST_NAME_IN_PROMPT='$(hostNameInPromptHelper 9)'
# left prompt
export PROMPT="%F{cyan}%${PROMPT_PERCENTAGE}<◀︎<%f" # truncation based on terminal width
PROMPT+='%(l.' # inner truncation group
PROMPT+="%F{cyan}%${LENGTH_OF_USERNAME}>‣>%n%>>%f " # username truncated
PROMPT+="${HOST_NAME_IN_PROMPT}"
PROMPT+='.)' # end truncation
PROMPT+='%F{magenta}%1~%f%<< ' # pwd 1 depth
PROMPT+='%# ' # privilege group
```

I replaced the old line `PROMPT+="%-${inWidth}(l. %F{blue}%5>‣>%m%>>%f.) " # hostname truncated` with a function call `PROMPT+="${HOST_NAME_IN_PROMPT}"`.  This is so that I can check the length of the current directory, and then either display the **hostname** or if the current directory is too long then not display the hostname.

## things which helped me come to this solution

1. `[[ ${PWD##*/} == ${HOME##*/} ]]` returns true if you are in your home directory
2. `${#PWD##*/}` [gives the length of the present working directory without calling a subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-a-bash-script)

## conclusion

What I wanted to do was not possible if I wanted to keep the entire prompt to a certain percentage of my terminal screen as seen in the previously named `widthHelper` function call.

I was able to get to a point where my terminal would not display a portion of my `PROMPT` if I entered a directory with a long name (See definition for `hostNameInPromptHelper` above).  I also tweaked the values for the percentage of my screen that is the prompt (i.e. `PROMPT_PERCENTAGE='$(termWidthPercentHelper 30)'`) and the value set for the percentage of my screen that the length of the directory name can take up before I don't display the hostname (i.e. `HOST_NAME_IN_PROMPT='$(hostNameInPromptHelper 9)'`). These values work for me but if you might want to tweak these until you like your prompt.

### sources

- https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html
- [Get current directory name (without full path) in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-a-bash-script)
- https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion
- https://linuxhint.com/length_of_string_bash/